# Execute command give top: failed tty get

Tags: php, ssh, centos

I have a problem when executing this line shown below.

```
sudo /usr/bin/env TERM=xterm /usr/bin/php /home/folder/folder/script.php -b val -a 2018-07-01
```

It gives me a error `top: failed tty get`. When I try it with `php -f` it gives me another problem similar to `php --help`.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [error] => 1
            [return] =>     top: failed tty get


        )
```

The result that I want is to execute command with success not error I execute this command with SSH in a PHP script.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/304470/problems-with-cron-script-and-term-definition-using-top-command

Comment: See how I got around it `top -n 1 -b > top-out`, https://github.com/plinker-rpc/system/blob/master/src/System.php#L477

Comment: top -n 1 -b not working @LawrenceCherone i want to exec the line on top without getting this error

Comment: "I execute this command with SSH in a PHP script." Please [edit] your question to include the code in your PHP script that executes this command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Really could do with a copy of your PHP script here (as requested in comments) to confirm, but based on what you've provided:

It appears what you are trying to do it run "top" in some configuration that requires terminal in a PHP script.

```
/home/folder/folder/script.php
<?php

exec('top -n 1 -b', $out, $error);

print_r($out);
```

called by

```
/usr/bin/php /home/folder/folder/script.php
```

There are two solutions:

1) Using the above parameters (`-n 1 -b`) runs in batch mode for one iteration - tested Centos7. This should not need terminal and adds the output to an array. This could be what you need. But if it still fails:

2) Otherwise, you can specify the `TERM=xterm` - it looks like this is what you've attempted to do, but you need to to it inside the exec, and not in the shell that calls the php script.

```
/home/folder/folder/script.php
<?php

exec('TERM=xterm top -n 1 -b', $out, $error);

print_r($out);
```

called by

```
/usr/bin/php /home/folder/folder/script.php
```